# odd behaviour with variable units

Tags: r

I have noticed a strange behaviour when using `units` and `label` from the `Hmisc` package, specifically when I subset a `data.frame` that has `labels` and `units` applied.

If both `labels` and `units` have been applied to a variable, subsetting does nothing, but if there are only `units` sub setting seems to remove the units.

**Example:**

```
library(Hmisc)
df <- head(iris)

Hmisc::label(df$Petal.Length) <- 'Flower'
units(df$Petal.Length) <- 'cm'
units(df$Sepal.Length) <- 'mm'

sapply(df, Hmisc::units) # still has both units 
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#         "mm"           ""         "cm"           ""           "" 

df <- df[!is.na(df$Species), ] # subset (there's no NAs so not actually removing anything)
sapply(df, Hmisc::units) # only the column with a label still has units
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#           ""           ""         "cm"           ""           ""
```

**Question:**

Is this a bug? or is there a reason for this behaviour? I have read the documentation for the `Hmisc` functions but can't see anything obvious as to why this happens.

**Session Info:**

Using R 3.6.1, RStudio 1.1.456 and Hmisc 4.3-0

Comment: It is removing the attributes `..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mm"`

Comment: yeah, but why is it doing that? Is there some documentation that explains it? And why only for the variable that doesn't also have a label?

Comment: Not sure, strangely, the `filter` is not doing that `df %>% filter(!is.na(Species)) %>% sapply(Hmisc::units)#
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
        "mm"           ""         "cm"           ""           ""`

Comment: can confirm `filter` from `dplyr` does not drop attributes. I usually try to stick to base R, but this is good enough. Still confusing as to why it's happening though :P